# Laravel Implict Binding got No query results for model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-routing

I want suggestion how to handle and which method is best one. **Implicit Binding** or **Normal Binding** method.

I'm using Laravel route implicit binding. when I post wrong ID, I got error **No query results for model** how to handle in controller not **Exception Handler**. Now I done with exception handler but need better solution to handle this or avoid Implicit binding.

//Web.php

```
Route::delete('/master/user/department/{department}/delete', ['as' => 'master.user.department.destroy', 'middleware' => 'permission:master.user.department.destroy', 'uses' => 'Master\User\DepartmentController@destroy']);
```

//DepartmentContrller.php

```
public function destroy(Department $department)
{
        try {
            $department->delete();
            return redirect(route('master.user.department.index'))->with('success', array(' Department Deleted successfully'));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return back()->with('criticalError', array($e->getMessage()));
        }
}
```

//Handler.php

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException)
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('custom_modal', ['Model Not Found Exception', $exception->getMessage()]);
}
```

The below code is perfectly work, I would like to know which method is best one. 
//DepartmentContrller.php

```
public function destroy($id)
{
        try {
            $department=Department::find($id);
            if($department){
                $department->delete();
                return redirect(route('master.user.department.index'))->with('success', array(' Department Deleted successfully'));
            }
            else{
                return back()->with('criticalError', array('Department is not found.'));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return back()->with('criticalError', array($e->getMessage()));
        }
}
```

Comment: Laravel find() will return NULL when the record is not found. You can use is_null() to check the response of the find method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods are valid. It is up to you to choose which method is appropriate for your situation.

Implicit model binding will let you get code out the door quicker, but you give up some control.

Explicit (normal) binding will take more code to write, but you have complete control over how the exceptions are caught and handled.

Just an FYI, if you stick with implicit binding, the `ModelNotFoundException` has a `getModel()` method that will give you the name of the model that caused the exception. This will let you customize your exception handling a little bit more, but still doesn't give you the same control as handling the exception where it happens.

Answer (score -3):

All of above method be work for you but you can override elqoent method --find() in case of you in your respective model

```
// Put this in any model and use
// Modelname::find($id);
public static function findOrCreate($id)
{
     $obj = static::find($id);
     return $obj ?: new static;
}
```

[in depth description](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_find)

Comment: This is true when I what to create new record when the record is not found, How can I manage the exception if the record is not found?

Comment: The `findOrNew()` method of the Eloquent query builder already does this.